# how to filter array which contain key and value

Tags: javascript

I have an array of JavaScript objects

```
[
   {path: "/login", meta: {nav :true},
   {path: "/welcome"}
   {path: "/logout", meta: {nav :true},
   {path: "/home"}
]
```

i need output like

```
[
   {path: "/login", meta: {nav :true},
   {path: "/logout", meta: {nav :true},
]
```

can you help me ?
thanks

on test

```
let data = [
  {path: "/login", meta: {nav :true}, { path: "/welcome" } ,
  {path: "/logout", meta: {nav :true},
  {path: "/home"},
]
data.filter(function(route) {
    return route.meta;
});
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: `filter` returns a new array and does not mutate the original array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/vi/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let arr = [
   {path: "/login", meta: {nav :true}},
   {path: "/welcome", meta: null},
   {path: "/logout", meta: {nav :true}},
   {path: "/home"}
];
let res = arr.filter(({meta}) => meta && meta.nav === true);
 
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.filter()`:

```js
var arr = [
   {path: "/login", meta: {nav :true}},
   {path: "/welcome"},
   {path: "/logout", meta: {nav :true}},
   {path: "/home"}
];
 var res = arr.filter(({meta}) => meta);
 
 console.log(res);
```

The issue with your code is that you do not have the left hand assignment for the filtered results:

```js
let data = [
  {path: "/login", meta: {nav :true}}, 
  { path: "/welcome"} ,
  {path: "/logout", meta: {nav :true}},
  {path: "/home"}
]
var res = data.filter(function(route) {
    return route.meta;
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: ops thank you very match

Comment: @user8210918 you can approve the answer if that was helpful